# MVVM: What is the purpose of a separate ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

If the code-behind for the `View` is meant to consist of nothing but the constructor with the `InitializeComponent()` call, why not just use `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` and use the view itself as a view model?

I get that this *technically* violates the Single Responsibility Principle, but since the XAML and code-behind are defined independently from each other, it doesn't cause the usual mess. Having separate view models for everything causes more mess to the file structure.

Comment: For one thing, it allows you to run unit tests without requiring UI automation.

Comment: The ViewModel is meant to be UI independent to allow unit testing.

Comment: You are wrong. Code behind is meant to be used for anything but UI-related code. if you have custom animations or etc., you are free to use them in your code behind. I refer you to a good article:"Advanced MVVM"

Comment: Using viewModels, you can have hierarchical structure for your project and you can freely switch your presentation layer with another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewModel describes view state. For testing and reusing purposes it must be UI independent. 
Benefits:

1. You can cover ViewModel by unit tests and you haven't to refer UI
   classes in test
2. You can reuse your ViewModel on other UI targets:
   console app, WinForms App, UWP app, Xamarin iOS/Android App, no
   display IoT project. You'll need to write only view for new target platform.
3. Sometimes even in WPF and MVVM you have to write some code behind for View-only purpose because it may be much more simpler, readable and reliable then create some new entity for that. And you'll get mess if you have also ViewModel in code behind.